# Non-jailed SSH user getting /bin/bash permission denied

Tags: server, bash, permissions, ssh

I've set up a number of different users which each have their own jail directory. Inside this jailed directory they each have all the binaries and libraries they need copied over. SSH access is working for these users by using a Match block and using the `ChrootDirectory` option.

Since enabling this all my regular users are getting /bin/bash permission denied. I've checked the permissions on all the directories including `/`, `/bin` and the user's home directory. All seem to be okay.

I've also tried copying the binaries to the regular user directory just in case the match block isn't working correctly, however this did not make any difference.

When connecting over SSH the MOTD is displayed and then the permission denied message is displayed.

Comment: Does `/bin/bash` exist in an executable state in the jail? What are the owner and permissions?

Comment: The user that I'm trying to connect with shouldn't have any jails applied to them, this is just a regular user. The jailed users can SSH in fine

Comment: Okay.  Same question in the live non-chrooted filesystem, then.  Does `/bin/bash` exist? What are its permissions? Who is its owner?

Comment: Yep, /bin/bash exists.  /bin is root:root and 755, /bin/bash is root:root and 0644.

Comment: "`/bin/bash is root:root and 0644`" that will be the problem ...

Comment: sorry, it was actually 755, read another file's line by mistake

Answer (score 1):

This will be the problem:

> `/bin/bash` is `root:root` and `0644`

On sane systems

```
$ ls -l /bin/bash 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1037464 Sep  1  2015 /bin/bash
```

the `bash` should be executable by everyone, which is `755`

```
chmod 755 /bin/bash
```

should make it working for you.